# How to update an object using for-of loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, for-loop

Obj.users is an array of users in the form of objects, I want to add an additional property i:e "priority" to the each user object. Since I don't have the index of each user's object so I'm trying to update it with the loop variable but when I console.log it, It's not getting updated.

> Obj.users and interests are both arrays.

```
router.get("/", auth, async function (req, res) {
  const { email, interests } = req.user;
  const obj = {};
  var counter = 0;
  obj.users = await User.find(req.user._id);
  for (var i of obj.users) {
    for (var j of interests) {
      if (i.interests.includes(j)) {
        counter = counter + 1;
      }
    }
    i.priority = counter;
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(obj.users);
});
```

Comment: Consider not using `var` and change them to `let`? Also, why use `i` and `j` and not `let user of obj.users`, etc?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the `forEach` or JavaScript, it's that Mongoose objects are [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), you can't add properties to them. You could make a new object with all of the properties and then add a property to that, but that won't add the property to the object in MongoDB. To do that, you have to do an actual MongoDB update operation.

Comment: (And as @evolutionxbox said, it's not the problem but `var` is deprecated in modern JavaScript, and meaningful names like `user` and `interest` help people understand your code much better than `i` and `j`. You could even go further and use `const`, because you never assign a new value to those [you just try to modify the state of the object, which is fine with a `const` but not, again, with a Mongoose object].)